Georgian Causative verbs
Do Georgian causative verbs in -(ev-)in-ebs have conjugation II forms, which would then have a passive-of-causative meaning like "is caused to VERB"? Neither Aronson nor Hewitt answers this question.

Even in Armenian, which unlike Georgian is Indo-European and not agglutinative, it is indeed possible and both features are productive, though combining them is relatively rare in practice.

Could you search the web for the causative+passive forms of some common Georgian verbs?  Seems like you only need to find one legitimate usage to prove it is possible.

By "conjugation II", do you mean Class II (intransitive verbs), or Series II (aorist + optative screeves)?
